# C# - Is overloading methods with different types more performant than using type checking in a single method?

Tags: c#, performance, overloading, typechecking

Say I have this:

```
    public void DoThing (string text)
    {
        DoThingWithText(text);
    }

    public void DoThing (int number)
    {
        DoThingWithNumbers(number);
    }
```

And compare it to this:

```
    public void DoThing (object obj)
    {
        if (obj is string text)
            DoThingWithText(text);

        if (obj is int number)
            DoThingWithNumbers(number);
    }
```

Would there be a performance difference here, and if so how significant?

Comment: Well, you could have tried benchmarking this yourself... Also [this](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: I'd say, yes, there is a performance difference - overloads will be quicker as the call to the overload is resolved at compile time - not runtime with an if. However you should really test this kind of thing yourself.

Comment: More importantly than performance, the first one gives you compile time type checking--generally you can only call DoThing with strings or ints. The second one allows you to call DoThing with any old rubbish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be a performance difference. It will be faster having typespecific methods, but unless it is to be done hundreds of times per second, it should not be a significant difference.

The more dynamic and generic you make methods and classes, the more CPU heavy it will be on the computer processing it. I guess if its being run on a slow computer it might make more of a difference.

As DavidG suggested, you could try to run performance tests yourself. You could store DateTime.Now before running a bunch of these methods and another test using the type testing of an object, and then output the difference with a new DateTime.Now after.

Comment: Or use a `System.Timer.Stopwatch`  to keep track of time instead.

Comment: Just did the tests. Very straightforward code, basically the same concept as in my question post but all leading up to a method which does nothing. Looped over 300000 times. Using typechecking took 0,0442896 seconds while the type specific overloads took 0,0079419 seconds. If I did it right (first time doing this kinda thing), your assertion is confirmed, much faster using type specification. But again first time testing performance so I might have done it wrong. Thanks, though

Comment: I am glad it worked. Good point by Eric Wu. The StopWatch is designed to help time things like this. As the test does seem to show, its not a huge difference, so it depends on what you are doing. It will probably be a problem to type check in the code, but there might be other benefits of being type specific as well. You wont end up sending an object type to it that it wont support.